# How does one transform JSON object names as an element name? Also, remove a nested object?

Tags: json, mule-studio, dataweave

Using Dataweave I'm attempting to transform this:

```
{
    "ConcurrentAsyncGetReportInstances": {
        "Max": 200,
        "Remaining": 200
    },
    "ConcurrentSyncReportRuns": {
        "Max": 20,
        "Remaining": 20
    },
    "DailyAnalyticsDataflowJobExecutions": {
        "Max": 50,
        "Remaining": 50
    },
    "DailyApiRequests": {
        "Max": 6175000,
        "Remaining": 6174972,
        "Ant Migration Tool": {
            "Max": 0,
            "Remaining": 0
        },
        "CLM_service_api": {
            "Max": 0,
            "Remaining": 0
        },
        "CRM_service_api": {
            "Max": 0,
            "Remaining": 0
        }
    },
    "DailyAsyncApexExecutions": {
        "Max": 325000,
        "Remaining": 324902
 }
```

Into this:

```
[
{
    "name":"ConcurrentAsyncGetReportInstances",
    "max":200,
    "remaining":200 
},
{
    "name":"ConcurrentSyncReportRuns",
    "max":"20",
    "remaining":"20"    
},
{
    "name":"DailyAnalyticsDataflowJobExecutions",
    "max":50,
    "remaining":50  
},
{
    "name":"DailyApiRequests",
    "max":6175000,
    "remaining":6174972 
},
{
    "name":"DailyAsyncApexExecutions",
    "max":325000,
    "remaining":324902  
}
]
```

Also - note I don't want any nested values like in DailyApiRequests

I have attempted the map function but am uncertain how to properly use.  All the examples I have seen dont seem to show this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using DataWeave

```
%dw 1.0
%input payload application/json
%output application/json
---
payload pluck ((value,key) -> {
    name: key,
    max: value.Max,
    remaining: value.Remaining
  } 
)
```

Comment: Thanks!  Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in **JavaScript** you can use package `lodash` and use its `map` function:

### Code

```js
const _ = require('lodash')

const obj = ... // your object above
const res = _.map(obj, (v, k) => ({
  name: k, 
  max: v.Max, 
  remaining: v.Remaining
}))

console.log(res)
```

### Output

[image]

Look at `lodash` documentation [here](https://lodash.com/docs/#map)

The other thing you can do is to **iterate through the object properties** by hand and do the **map** by yourself, but I think you will end up reinventing the wheel and doing exactly what `lodash` does ;) so, give it a try. By the way, that package is amazing, it is *extremely useful*.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Josué 's, but without introducing unneeded dependencies.

```
const obj = {} // your object above
const res = Object.entries(obj).map( [k, v] => ({
  name: k, 
  ...v
}))
```

Another example, but with a simple loop:

```
const obj = {}; // your object above
const res = []; // New object
for(const [k, v] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  res.push({
    ...v,
    name: k
  });
}
```

An example that will work in a 10-year old browser:

```
var obj = {}; // your object above
var res = []; // New object
for(var key in obj) {
  if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
  res.push({
    name: k, 
    max: obj[k].Max, 
    remaining: obj[k].Remaining
  });
}
```